# How to delete a word in each line of a text file, error message

Tags: python, text-files

I made a program to remove the first word in each line. The code works fine, but as soon as it reads the result, it throws me an error message.
I don't understand why, it should work. I didn't figure out how to fix this mistake, can you help me?

demofile.txt

```
>=3 1 2 3 
>=2 4 5 6
>=1 1 2 4 4
```

code

```
 #remove first word in each line from demofile
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
with open('output.txt', mode='w', newline='\n') as output:
    for i in list(lines):
        # remove operators and first number from demofile
        sfn = i.split(" ", 1)
        #print(sfn)
        newfilename = sfn[1]
        output.write(newfilename)
```

result

```
1 2 3 

4 5 6

1 2 4 4

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Pifko\dp\skuska.py", line 20, in <module>
    newfilename = sfn[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a trailing newline in your input file.